# How to change the color of \StageDir in Dramatist?

Tags: color, dramatist

I'm writing a play and I would like to give the directions different colours. However, when trying the obvious:

```
\usepackage{xcolor} \\\

\def\stdir{\color{red} \StageDir} \\\

\begin{drama} \\\

\stdir{text, text, text},
```

Then, from the first Stage direction in the text, everything turns red. I've been trying 
to redefine the `\StageDir`-command with an internal colour declaration, but to no avail. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to get only the `\StageDir` in a different colour?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

With `etoolbox` it's quite easy, because `\StageDir` just uses the `stagedir` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dramatist}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{stagedir}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\Character[Billy Prose]{BILLY}{billy}
\Character[Sally Verse]{SALLY}{sally}

\StageDir{text, text, text}

\begin{drama*}

\sallyspeaks I am a poet \\
I know it\\
I like to speak in short lines\\
Like this\\
My cat is gray\\
My fish is dead\\
Because the cat ate it\\
I am\\
A very difficult person\\
To have a conversation with.\\

\end{drama*}

\StageDir{text, text, text}

\begin{drama}

\billyspeaks I like to talk like a normal person. Your cat is lame. I have a gerbil named Phil. He 
sleeps in my dresser. I'm so sorry that my examples sounds insane.

\end{drama}

\end{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot egreg! Just out of curiosity, since \direct does not have an environment option, I suppose I can't use this neat way of changing also embedded direction into f.ex. blue or green, right? Any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: @Martin Not without a complete example; unfortunately the documentation of `dramatist` has no example at all.